# Docker thinpool storage clarification

Tags: docker

I am looking for some clarification on Docker Storage.  In my CentOS server configured Docker with thinpool storage.

While running the container instance I see its mounting file system in /var/lib/containers directory.
*My question is:*

1. What data storage in the thinkpool?
2. What data stored in the /var/lib/containers directory.
3. Is there any recommended size for the think pool storage?
4. Docker CIS recommendation is to create separate partition for containers, if we use the thinkpool still do we need to create separate partition? Is there any security risk having /var/lib part of root file system?

thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devicemapper setup contains all of the filesystem content in all loaded Docker images and running containers.  It doesn't contain data in named volumes or bind-mounted host directories.

If you have an option to upgrade to a new enough host OS and Docker to use the overlay2 storage driver instead, it is much easier to manage (precisely because you don't have the "choose how much space to allocate to Docker" question).  There's no particular security implications of using overlay2, or devicemapper with a local file, or devicemapper with a dedicated partition, above and beyond the security concerns Docker brings on its own.

You can probably cast a guess as to how much space you'll actually need based on the size reported in `docker images`.  If you're only using prebuilt images on Docker Hub, they're often 200 MB or less and the default space allocation (IIRC 20 GB) might actually be fine.  If you're using locally-built images and especially if you're not careful about space usage (you `RUN apt-get install build-essential`) plan on each built image being 1 GB or more, and size according to your needs.

There's nothing to see in `/var/lib/docker` and the details vary by installation.  Don't go poking around in there.